# axios equivalent to curl --upload-file

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, axios

I'm trying to upload a gif to Gfycat using their [public API](https://developers.gfycat.com/api/#uploading-a-file-to-create-a-new-gfycat).

This is done using cURL on the command line with:

```
curl https://filedrop.gfycat.com --upload-file /tmp/name
```

I attempted to convert this to Node.js using [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios):

```js
axios.post("https://filedrop.gfycat.com", {
    data: fs.createReadStream("/tmp/name")
}).then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

but an error with the message

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<Error><Code>PreconditionFailed</Code><Message>At least one of the pre-conditions you specified did not hold</Message><Condition>Bucket POST must be of the enclosure-type multipart/form-data</Condition><RequestId>6DD49EB33F41DE08</RequestId><HostId>/wyrORPfBWHZk5OuLCrH9Mohwu33vOUNc6NzRSNT08Cxd8PxSEZkzZdj/awpMU6UkpWghrQ1bLY=</HostId></Error>
```

is printed to the console.

How my Node.js code different than the cURL command and what would be the equivalent code using axios to the cURL command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You <s>need to use `FormaData()`</s> can use [`form-data`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) and may also need to use [`concat-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concat-stream):

```
const concat = require("concat-stream")
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fd = new FormData();
const fs = require('fs');

fd.append("hello", "world")
fd.append("file", fs.createReadStream("/tmp/name"))
fd.pipe(concat({encoding: 'buffer'}, data => {
  axios.post("https://filedrop.gfycat.com", data, {
    headers: fd.getHeaders()
  })
}))
```

Credit: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/318#issuecomment-277231394

Comment: I'm using axios from Node.js, FormData is only used for axios in the browser.

Comment: @Shadowfacts to use form-data in node you can do `npm install --save form-data` then you can import using `import * as FormData from 'form-data'` in your project. If you're using Typescript remember to also install types `npm install --save-dev @types/form-data`