# How to convert this curl request into nodejs axios put request

Tags: node.js, curl, axios, xmlhttprequest

Hello I am trying to upload a file using axios but it simply is not working but the curl request is working fine with me.

Here is the curl request

```
curl -X PUT "https://url.com" \
        -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" \
        --upload-file ./Downloads/image.jpg
```

I am just trying to understand how to upload a file on the server side and send a request using axios that is similar to the curl request that I have above.

Here is what I tried with axios

```
const Formdata = require('form-data');
const axios = require('axios');

const data = new Formdata();
data.append("file" , './image.jpg');

axios.default.put("https://url.com" , data , {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
    }
})
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.warn(error);
})
```

Thank you

Comment: @jeeves Hello I have edited the question to show you what I tried with axios

Comment: @jeeves I am still running into an error, I guess my error originates from the ```--upload-file``` command do you know how to do that method ?

Comment: @jeeves how do you add a file stream

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42190516/axios-equivalent-to-curl-upload-file